# The best way for making speciall matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I want to make the below matrix in r:

```r
1 0 0 4
0 2 0 5
0 0 3 6
```

I used the below code:

```r
matrix(c(1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,4,5,6),nrow=3)
```

My code works. But I do not like my solution way. I am thinking to find the simplest way for making this matrix. Do you think my code is the simplest code for making this matrix? If not, could anyone writes a simpler code than my one?

Comment: Why do you not like it? What would make it simpler?

Comment: Seems quite simply to me. But you could try: `cbind(diag(1:3), 4:6)` which does the trick but isn't "simpler" in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you Martin Gal. I like your code much more than my code. You wrote fewer numbers than me to make that matrix. I mean I put all numbers in a vector then I make my matrix.

Comment: Actually, I am making some matrix as follows:
0 1 1;
1 0 1;
1 1 0;
matrix(rep(c(0,1,1,1),3),nrow=3,ncol=3)
and
1  3   5  7  9  11;
13  15  17  19;
21   23  25  27;
29 31 33 35;
i<-0:17 matrix(2*i+1,nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)
and
1      0.5   0.5;
0.5     1     0.5;
0.5   0.5    1;
matrix(rep(c(1,0.5,0.5,0.5),3),nrow=3,ncol=3)

For all the above matrixes I have written code (as you see below each matrix) . If you want to make the above matrixes, will you use my codes or will you have other simpler ways for making the above matrixes?

Answer (score 2):

Your first matrix

```r
> cbind(diag(1:3), 4:6)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    4
[2,]    0    2    0    5
[3,]    0    0    3    6
```

Your second one

```r
> matrix(1, nrow=3, ncol=3) - diag(1, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    1    1    0
```

Your third

```r
> matrix(seq(1, 35, 2), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9   11
[2,]   13   15   17   19   21   23
[3,]   25   27   29   31   33   35
```

and your final

```r
> matrix(0.5, nrow=3, ncol=3) + diag(0.5, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.5  0.5
[2,]  0.5  1.0  0.5
[3,]  0.5  0.5  1.0
```

As @jay.sf pointed out, there is a more sophisticated solution for the second and fourth matrix:

```r
# second matrix
`diag<-`(matrix(1, 3, 3), 0)
# fourth matrix
`diag<-`(matrix(0.5, 3, 3), 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Very interesting.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer, if you are satisfied. :-)

Comment: Proposition second matrix: `\`diag<-\`(matrix(1, 3, 3), 0)`.

Comment: @jay.sf Very nice solution! Can you explain it to me? To be honest: I don't understand, how and why it's working.

Comment: @MartinGal In R practically anything is a function. When you do `diag(M) <- 0` you're actually calling the diagonal assignment function `\`diag<-\`(x, value)` (just type `\`diag<-\`` to see the code, which is different from `diag`). This also works for lots of other functions like e.g. `\`colnames<-\`()`, `\`<-\`()`, `\`[\`(c(1, 2, 99), 3)` ... The advantage is, in some cases you can do the stuff at the RHS and save a line of code. _Read more:_ http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#all-calls

Comment: @jay.sf Thanks a lot, especially for the link. Didn't know about that.